# Bifurcation diagram

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Consider the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_diagram) $x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n)$, whose bifurcation diagram is shown below for $2.4 < r < 4.0$:
[image]
I need to find a particular value of $r$ so that "attracting $2^k$ periodic points (a result after $k$ instances of period doubling) accumulate". This was one part of my lab assignment, but I do not understand what it is saying. I do see some nearly-empty small gaps in the above bifurcation diagram for certain values of $r$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute limit point r of [period doubling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724964/logistic-map-bifurcation-diagram?rq=1) cascade. One can do it:

- [numerically](https://juliacomputing.com/blog/2017/11/27/high-precision-feigenbaum-alpha-calc-using-julia.html)
- visually : zoom into placed of period doubling bifurcation , like as in [fig 7 from this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.2262.pdf)